# I have two matrices that I have converted to a grayscale image and I want to find the mean SSIM value between them (python)

Tags: python, numpy, grayscale, ssim

For example I have:

```
X = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
Y = [[1,4,7],[5,5,1]]

a=np.array(X)
grayA=(a-np.amin(a))/(np.amax(a)-np.amin(a))

b=np.array(Y)
grayB=(b-np.amin(b))/(np.amax(b)-np.amin(b))
```

However, when I do

```
compare_ssim(grayA, grayB)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: win_size exceeds image extent.  If the input is a multichannel (color) image, set multichannel=True.
```

I tried

```
compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, multichannel = True)
```

but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is produced because the default value of win_size is 7 and

```py
np.any((np.asarray(grayA.shape) - win_size) < 0)
```

To solve the problem, you should define `win_size` to be odd and smaller than any of the image dimensions. So, in your example, it should be `win_size=1`.

However, when win_size is equal to 1, you need to set `use_sample_covariance=False` because if not, the code needs to divide by 0. Therefore, your example would work using

```py
compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, win_size=1, use_sample_covariance=False)
```

The problem vanishes if your images are 7x7 or larger. For instance:

```py
X = np.random.rand(7,7)
Y = np.random.rand(7,7)
compare_ssim(X, Y)
```